# Time-dependent thermal expansion of air?

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, gas

Every solid, gas, liquid has a coefficient of thermal expansion (measured in e.g. %/K). This assumes an equilibrium state at the new temperature

**My question is:** what is the time rate of change thermal expansion of air (i.e. the units would be %/K/s)? Therefore enabling you to answer not only the question "what is the new volume?" but also "how long did it take to reach that new volume?"

I'm not expecting a simple relationship as there are spatial and physical non linearities in the problem. But are there e.g. empirical estimates?

**Application:** I have hot gas flowing into a duct in which a fan is installed. The gas is not at equilibrium (i.e. it is still expanding). The velocity in the duct will increase above the fan-induced velocity due to the expansion of the gas. I want to quantify this increase in velocity.

Is the answer: solve the compressible Navier Stokes equations?

Comment: Under what conditions of heating are you asking about? You realize that the rate of thermal expansion depends on how fast it is heated.

Comment: Air is very compressible.  The ideal gas law normally applies, not coefficients of thermal expansion.

Comment: @AlNejati I have hot gas entering a duct installed with a fan. The gas is not at equilibrium state (i.e. it is still expanding). This expansion is increasing the velocity in the duct. I want to estimate this increase in volume/mass flow, velocity.

Comment: @DavidWhite my understanding was that you one derives the isobaric and isochoric thermal expansion from the ideal gas law?

Answer (score 0):

Air has a thermal conductivity value but it is very dependent on convective currents. In an experiment you would have trouble controlling how fast you got the heat into the air depending upon the geometry due to convection, i.e. surface area, external temp, surface characteristics etc.   The thermal conductivity of air is very low in insulation because the air is trapped.  Assuming you had this low constant value you could calculate the heating rate and hence the expansion.